# Artisan migrate command no output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to setup already made project but I'm stuck at the migrating the DB. I'm using Laravel (5.6.34) on PHP 7.2.9, and MySQL (8.0.12). If I try to run `php artisan migrate` command I'm getting no output, command stays "active" but nothing happens, no errors.

I tried making fresh project, adding migration and running the same command, same thing. I noticed that all other (or at least bunch of them I tried) artisan commands are working but only migrate one doesn't.

.env info is correct and mysql is up and running.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Let's check artisan file, maybe it's empty. I got this error before too and it's because of empty artisan file.

Comment: clear cache and view and make sure you changed database details

Comment: @SangNguyen artisan files is not empty..

Comment: @C2486 I cleared all possible cache, and double checked database details. If I on purpose enter wrong DB info I get actual error, but with correct info I get nothing.

Comment: Please share all steps you did for new setup ?

Comment: @C2486 I cloned repo, did composer install, populated .env, generated app key and tried to run migrations. Everything else works, serving it and other artisan commands but migration one..

Comment: did you try by creating new migration and then `php artisan migrate` ?

Comment: @C2486 Yes, it doesn't change anything. Still empty output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning the password to DB User solved this issue for me (be sure populate DB_PASSWORD inside .env)

```
mysqladmin -u YOURDBUSER password 'newpassword'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following;
 1. Check your migration files for content.
 2. Flush config with `php artisan config:clear`
 3. Check if database is connected using tinker. Run `php artisan tinker` then paste in this code; `DB::connection()->getPdo();`
 4. If PDO object is returned, your app is connected to the database. If not and `PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused'` is returned then mysql is not running. If database does not exist, you get the error `PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database [your_db]`.

Comment: I get nothing after I enter `DB::connection()->getPdo();`, it's same as if I type command for migration. I'm 100% sure migrations are correctly written as they are working on other PC.